NextJS 14: Can't get 404s to show using generateStaticParams()
I am using dynamic slugs to load the data, which works. However, my 404s stopped working, instead it shows this error now:
Error: Page "/[slug]/page" is missing param "/test" in "generateStaticParams()", which is required with "output: export" config.
Here is my page.tsx:
import { PRODUCTS } from "@/data/data";
import DetailsPage from '@/components/PDP/page';
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation';

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const products = await PRODUCTS;
 
  return products.map((product) => ({
    slug: product.slug,
  }))
}


function DetailsPageWrapper({ params }: { params: any }) {

  const { slug } = params;

  if (!slug) {
    return notFound();
  }

  return (
    <DetailsPage slug={slug} />
  );
}

export default DetailsPageWrapper;

How can I display my 404 page if the slugs are not found?

So apparently, the issue occurs on the local dev environment only. When deployed to the production, I see the correct 404s rendering.
